# Particular unicode characters are not shown in some fixed width fonts for some editors in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, fonts, text-editors, unicode, fixed-width

I am grateful to the user [Berend](https://superuser.com/users/361452/berend) for turning my attention in the right direction: originally the question blamed fonts, which turned out not to be the case.

While there are lots of beautiful fonts with very good unicode support, I could find only two monospace fonts installable on Windows that show the particular unicode characters I need (such as , , , ...) in all editors where I would like to use them: [GNU Unifont](http://unifoundry.com/unifont/index.html) and [Everson Mono](https://www.evertype.com/emono/) . While they are ... well ..., ok, there are several better designed monospace fonts which only show  these characters in some editors.

Namely, for example, Consolas shows them in Notepad, Notepad++, Word but does not show them in Emacs, Wordpad and Geany.

In case of Emacs (which I need in the first place) I tried Emacs for Windows, the one installed from cygwin and the one installed from mingw64, none of them displays these characters.

Windows 10 Pro 2004 build 19041.572 Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.31.0

Further update - seems like e. g. Consolas does not in fact have these characters, some apps substitute them using some other fonts and some don't.

Comment: I don't know if there's an easy way to find a font that includes a certain character, but the ones I just tried on my machine all contain the glyphs in your question. Is it just these numbers you are missing or are there others? These are the ones I tried: Cascadia Mono, Consolas, Courier, Courier New, Fixedsys, Lucida Console and Monotxt. I think most of these come with Windows (except perhaps Cascadia).

Comment: @Berend Many thanks for this information! Seems like I have to investigate further: I tried Consolas, Courier, Courier New, Fixedsys and Lucida Console, none of them had these characters. I am doing this in emacs, so maybe there is some issue between emacs and windows?

Comment: No this is probably not emacs problem: I just looked into the character map for Consolas and could not find the symbols there. Could you please tell a little bit about your configuration? Mine is Windows 10 Pro 2004 build 19041.572 Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.31.0

Comment: OK investigating further, it seems that it is still more editor-related problem in general than anything else. The characters show up in Notepad, Notepad++, Word and do not show up in Emacs, Geany and Wordpad. Will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: You should probably try Courier New. That's pretty much my "go-to" for monospace (same-width) fonts. If you want a perfect "same-width same-height" font, at the risk of having to install a font, there is one out there called [Square](http://strlen.com/square/).

Comment: @Hashgrammer Alas, Courier New does not display these characters for me. I installed Square and it does, but I certainly prefer Unifont or Everson Mono to it which work for me too. Do you know why some fonts work and some don't??

Comment: @Berend Having investigated further, seems like these characters are being substituted from some other font. FontForge shows that, for example, Consolas does not have them.

Comment: I tried in Notepad++ and as far as I know, no font substitution is done there. Other special glyphs show up as an empty square, even though they exist in other fonts.

Comment: Alas, it appears that Windows may provide font substitution out of the box. So I guess it depends on the application you are using. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

For emacs, installing the [unicode-fonts](https://github.com/rolandwalker/unicode-fonts) package helped. The problem persists in Geany and Wordpad though, apparently for entirely different reasons.